# Launch top level screen from inside screen

Tags: gnu-screen

I am inside a screen session, and from there want to launch another screen. However I don't want the new screen to be within the existing ( or a child process of the existing ).

I.e. if I simply start screen from the existing screen I get a process tree like this:

```
├── screen 1
│    └── screen 2
```

but I want:

```
├── screen 1
├── screen 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the manpage, the `-m` option is what you want

```
   -m   causes screen  to  ignore  the  $STY  environment  variable.  With
        "screen  -m"  creation  of  a  new session is enforced, regardless
        whether screen is called from within  another  screen  session  or
        not.
```

So

```
$ screen -m
```

should do what you want.

This second screen instance can then be independently detached, re-attached, etc.  If you want this second screen to start off detached then `-d -m` is a good option pair.